# Subtraction of values between two csv files

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I have created two csv files containing terms and their frequency of two different type of articles (news and editorials). What I would like to do now is to find the most representative words for these categories.

This is a sample of the two files (words contained in news and words contained in editorials):

```
News                        Editorials

word count                  word count 
leaves 2                    raging 4  
raging 1                    war    6    
aliment 1                   attack  1
interpretation 1            terrorism 1
revolt 1                    knew 1
knew 4                      actor 2
cuisine 1                   revolt 7
```

To do so, I would like to subtract the frequency of the words occurring in both the csv files. If the value is positive it will go in a new csv file containg the most representative words for the subctrahend list, while if the value is negative will be part of a new csv file representing the minuend.

I am going step by step. So the first thing I am trying to do is selecting the "word" column from the first file and compare it with the "word" column from the second file, so I can start to compute the subtraction in case there are the same terms. But I don't know how to procede with it.

This is the code:

```
import csv

with open("words_news.csv", "r") as f, open("words_generic.csv","r") as g, open("news_values","w")as v, open("generic_values","w" as r:
    reader= csv.reader(f, delimiter=" ")
    reader_generic=csv.reader(g, delimiter=" ")
    writer = csv.writer(v, delimiter=" ")
    writer = csv.writer(r, delimiter=" ")                                                                                                         
    for row in reader:
        print(row[0])
```

This is the output:

```
word
leaves 
raging 
aliment
interpretation
```